# My tic tac toe game only works on the first click

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winforms, tic-tac-toe

I got this code from this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hYEEofdVOSY) and I modified it for education purposes. I inputted everything according to the video but when I try to run it, it only works for the top left button and doesn't show anything else. Reset button and New game button works fine, but I have yet to see if the score tab is working since it wont show the rest of the x's and o's.

```
#pragma endregion
        Boolean checker;
        int plus;
 
        void Enable_False() {
            btn1->Enabled = false;
            btn2->Enabled = false;
            btn3->Enabled = false;
            btn4->Enabled = false;
            btn5->Enabled = false;
            btn6->Enabled = false;
            btn7->Enabled = false;
            btn8->Enabled = false;
            btn9->Enabled = false;
        }
 
        void score(){
            {
                // Player X
                if (btn1->Text == "X" && btn2->Text == "X" && btn3->Text == "X"){
                    btn1->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::PowderBlue;
                    btn2->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::PowderBlue;
                    btn3->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::PowderBlue;
                    MessageBox::Show("Player X wins!", "Tic Tac Toe", MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Information);
                    plus = int::Parse(playerx->Text);
                    playerx->Text = Convert::ToString(plus + 1);
                    Enable_False();
                }
                if (btn1->Text == "X" && btn4->Text == "X" && btn7->Text == "X"){
                    btn1->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::PowderBlue;
                    btn4->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::PowderBlue;
                    btn7->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::PowderBlue;
                    MessageBox::Show("Player X wins!", "Tic Tac Toe", MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Information);
                    plus = int::Parse(playerx->Text);
                    playerx->Text = Convert::ToString(plus + 1);
                    Enable_False();
                }
                if (btn1->Text == "X" && btn5->Text == "X" && btn9->Text == "X"){
                    btn1->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::PowderBlue;
                    btn5->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::PowderBlue;
                    btn9->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::PowderBlue;
                    MessageBox::Show("Player X wins!", "Tic Tac Toe", MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Information);
                    plus = int::Parse(playerx->Text);
                    playerx->Text = Convert::ToString(plus + 1);
                    Enable_False();
                }
                if (btn4->Text == "X" && btn5->Text == "X" && btn6->Text == "X"){
                    btn4->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::PowderBlue;
                    btn5->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::PowderBlue;
                    btn6->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::PowderBlue;
                    MessageBox::Show("Player X wins!", "Tic Tac Toe", MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Information);
                    plus = int::Parse(playerx->Text);
                    playerx->Text = Convert::ToString(plus + 1);
                    Enable_False();
                }
                if (btn7->Text == "X" && btn8->Text == "X" && btn9->Text == "X"){
                    btn7->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::PowderBlue;
                    btn8->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::PowderBlue;
                    btn9->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::PowderBlue;
                    MessageBox::Show("Player X wins!", "Tic Tac Toe", MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Information);
                    plus = int::Parse(playerx->Text);
                    playerx->Text = Convert::ToString(plus + 1);
                    Enable_False();
                }
                if (btn3->Text == "X" && btn5->Text == "X" && btn7->Text == "X"){
                    btn3->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::PowderBlue;
                    btn5->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::PowderBlue;
                    btn7->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::PowderBlue;
                    MessageBox::Show("Player X wins!", "Tic Tac Toe", MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Information);
                    plus = int::Parse(playerx->Text);
                    playerx->Text = Convert::ToString(plus + 1);
                    Enable_False();
                }
                // Player O
                if (btn1->Text == "O" && btn2->Text == "O" && btn3->Text == "O"){
                    btn1->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::PowderBlue;
                    btn2->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::PowderBlue;
                    btn3->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::PowderBlue;
                    MessageBox::Show("Player O wins!", "Tic Tac Toe", MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Information);
                    plus = int::Parse(playero->Text);
                    playero->Text = Convert::ToString(plus + 1);
                    Enable_False();
                }
                if (btn1->Text == "O" && btn4->Text == "O" && btn7->Text == "O"){
                    btn1->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::PowderBlue;
                    btn4->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::PowderBlue;
                    btn7->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::PowderBlue;
                    MessageBox::Show("Player O wins!", "Tic Tac Toe", MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Information);
                    plus = int::Parse(playero->Text);
                    playero->Text = Convert::ToString(plus + 1);
                    Enable_False();
                }
                if (btn1->Text == "O" && btn5->Text == "O" && btn9->Text == "O"){
                    btn1->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::PowderBlue;
                    btn5->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::PowderBlue;
                    btn9->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::PowderBlue;
                    MessageBox::Show("Player O wins!", "Tic Tac Toe", MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Information);
                    plus = int::Parse(playero->Text);
                    playero->Text = Convert::ToString(plus + 1);
                    Enable_False();
                }
                if (btn4->Text == "O" && btn5->Text == "O" && btn6->Text == "O"){
                    btn4->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::PowderBlue;
                    btn5->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::PowderBlue;
                    btn6->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::PowderBlue;
                    MessageBox::Show("Player O wins!", "Tic Tac Toe", MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Information);
                    plus = int::Parse(playero->Text);
                    playero->Text = Convert::ToString(plus + 1);
                    Enable_False();
                }
                if (btn7->Text == "O" && btn8->Text == "O" && btn9->Text == "O"){
                    btn7->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::PowderBlue;
                    btn8->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::PowderBlue;
                    btn9->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::PowderBlue;
                    MessageBox::Show("Player O wins!", "Tic Tac Toe", MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Information);
                    plus = int::Parse(playero->Text);
                    playero->Text = Convert::ToString(plus + 1);
                    Enable_False();
                }
                if (btn3->Text == "O" && btn5->Text == "O" && btn7->Text == "O"){
                    btn3->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::PowderBlue;
                    btn5->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::PowderBlue;
                    btn7->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::PowderBlue;
                    MessageBox::Show("Player O wins!", "Tic Tac Toe", MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Information);
                    plus = int::Parse(playero->Text);
                    playero->Text = Convert::ToString(plus + 1);
                    Enable_False();
                }
 
            }
        }
    private: System::Void MyForm_Load(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    }
    private: System::Void btn1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
        if (checker == false) {
            btn1->Text = "X";
            checker = true;
        }
        else {
            btn1->Text = "O";
            checker = false;
        }
        score();
        btn1->Enabled = false;
    }
    private: System::Void btn2_Click(System::Object ^ sender, System::EventArgs ^ e) {
        if (checker == false) {
            btn2->Text = "X";
            checker = true;
        }
        else {
            btn2->Text = "O";
            checker = false;
        }
        score();
        btn2->Enabled = false;
    }
    private: System::Void btn3_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
        if (checker == false) {
            btn3->Text = "X";
            checker = true;
        }
        else {
            btn3->Text = "O";
            checker = false;
        }
        score();
        btn3->Enabled = false;
    }
    private: System::Void btn4_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
        if (checker == false) {
            btn4->Text = "X";
            checker = true;
        }
        else {
            btn4->Text = "O";
            checker = false;
        }
        score();
        btn4->Enabled = false;
    }
    private: System::Void btn5_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
        if (checker == false) {
            btn5->Text = "X";
            checker = true;
        }
        else {
            btn5->Text = "O";
            checker = false;
        }
        score();
        btn5->Enabled = false;
    }
    private: System::Void btn6_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
        if (checker == false) {
            btn6->Text = "X";
            checker = true;
        }
        else {
            btn6->Text = "O";
            checker = false;
        }
        score();
        btn6->Enabled = false;
    }
    private: System::Void btn7_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
        if (checker == false) {
            btn7->Text = "X";
            checker = true;
        }
        else {
            btn7->Text = "O";
            checker = false;
        }
        score();
        btn7->Enabled = false;
    }
    private: System::Void btn8_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
        if (checker == false) {
            btn8->Text = "X";
            checker = true;
        }
        else {
            btn8->Text = "O";
            checker = false;
        }
        score();
        btn8->Enabled = false;
    }
    private: System::Void btn9_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
        if (checker == false) {
            btn9->Text = "X";
            checker = true;
        }
        else {
            btn9->Text = "O";
            checker = false;
        }
        score();
        btn9->Enabled = false;
    }
 
private: System::Void reset_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    btn1->Enabled = true;
    btn2->Enabled = true;
    btn3->Enabled = true;
    btn4->Enabled = true;
    btn5->Enabled = true;
    btn6->Enabled = true;
    btn7->Enabled = true;
    btn8->Enabled = true;
    btn9->Enabled = true;
 
    btn1->Text = "";
    btn2->Text = "";
    btn3->Text = "";
    btn4->Text = "";
    btn5->Text = "";
    btn6->Text = "";
    btn7->Text = "";
    btn8->Text = "";
    btn9->Text = "";
 
    newbtn->Enabled = true;
 
    btn1->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::WhiteSmoke;
    btn2->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::WhiteSmoke;
    btn3->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::WhiteSmoke;
    btn4->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::WhiteSmoke;
    btn5->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::WhiteSmoke;
    btn6->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::WhiteSmoke;
    btn7->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::WhiteSmoke;
    btn8->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::WhiteSmoke;
    btn9->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::WhiteSmoke;
}
 
private: System::Void newBtn_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    btn1->Enabled = true;
    btn2->Enabled = true;
    btn3->Enabled = true;
    btn4->Enabled = true;
    btn5->Enabled = true;
    btn6->Enabled = true;
    btn7->Enabled = true;
    btn8->Enabled = true;
    btn9->Enabled = true;
 
    btn1->Text = "";
    btn2->Text = "";
    btn3->Text = "";
    btn4->Text = "";
    btn5->Text = "";
    btn6->Text = "";
    btn7->Text = "";
    btn8->Text = "";
    btn9->Text = "";
 
    playerx->Text = "0";
    playero->Text = "0";
 
    btn1->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::WhiteSmoke;
    btn2->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::WhiteSmoke;
    btn3->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::WhiteSmoke;
    btn4->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::WhiteSmoke;
    btn5->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::WhiteSmoke;
    btn6->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::WhiteSmoke;
    btn7->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::WhiteSmoke;
    btn8->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::WhiteSmoke;
    btn9->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::WhiteSmoke;
}
```

Comment: One of the major problems with following a video to write a program is that you bypass several crucial aspects of programming. You must know _what_ you're doing and _why_, in order to even have a chance at understanding what's gone wrong, how to isolate it and then how to fix it. You can develop these skills organically by writing your own small programs, building incrementally on what you know and testing often. There is no shortcut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing, I found the reason why the score cannot be displayed. Because the contents of the score box are not initialized when the program starts, `plus = int::Parse(playero->Text);` will cause an exception.

Solution:

Add the initialization of the score box in the MyForm_Load function.

```
private: System::Void MyForm_Load(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    playerx->Text = "0";
    playero->Text = "0";
}
```

Result:
[image]